# Product of holomorphic and nonholomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $f$ is holomorphic and $g$ is not holomorphic but $f\times g$ is holomorphic, must $f$ be zero identically? I think it must be true. If we write $f$ and $f\times g$ as power series we can compare terms on both sides and find a series for $g$, but there could be some issues like what if the series does not converge to $g$. There are counter examples to this when we are working with the reals for example $|x|\sin x$ but I'm thinking perhaps complex differentiability is strong enough.

Maybe $f$ could be zero at all the problem points of $g$ and this would work. Then what if we assume $f\neq 0$ for any $z$?

Comment: What’s wrong with $z^2 \cdot 1/z = z$? You could extend $1/z$ by any value at all when $z = 0$ if you need $g$ to be defined everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f(a)$ is not $0$, then $f$ is nonzero in a neighbourhood of $a$ and holomorphic here. Then $1/f$ is holomorphic in this neighbourhood and $g=fg/f$ is holomorphic here. The contra positive is that if $g$ is not holomorphic at $a$ then $f(a)=0$. Now if $f$ is not identically $0$ then $1/f$ exists in a punctured neighbourhood of $a$ because it has isolated zeros. Then again $g$ is holomorphic here.

If $g$ is assumed to be continuous then it is holomorhic at $a$ as well because it is a removable singularity. So we conclude in this case that $f$ must be identically $0$. If $g$ is not even continuous, then anything can of course happen at $a$ so $f$ need not be identically $0$.